# Can't map the response to the object

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to use Angular4 HttpClient with an observable object that I define. Unfortunately, I can't seem to map the response to the object.

The problem seems to be that I'm using httpclient (which returns json implicitly so there in no response.json() function) and as I understand it http is being deprecated? Anyway because of this the response.json() causes an error;
ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function

The code;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {JsonpModule, Jsonp, Response} from '@angular/http';

export class BucketList {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public creationdate: string) {
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class DocumentSearchService {

    constructor(private _http : HttpClient) { }

    getBucketList () : Observable<BucketList> {

      let serviceURL = "http://localhost:3000/listBuckets";

      return this._http.get(serviceURL, {withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json'})

      .map((response: Response) => <BucketList>(response.json())
      .catch((error: any) => window.console.log(error)));
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
// this.BucketList = this.DocumentSearchService.getBucketList

   this.BucketList = 
   this.DocumentSearchService.getBucketList().subscribe(value => {
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please? Googling and searching on SO have yielded no answers so far...

Thanks.

Comment: http .get<BucketList>(serviceURL)

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

`responseType: 'json'` and `response.json()` can be omitted because they are implied [by default](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient):

> The responseType value determines how a successful response body will be parsed. If responseType is the default json, a type interface for the resulting object may be passed as a type parameter to request().
>
> <...>
>
> ```
> get<T>(url: string, options: {
>     headers?: HttpHeaders,
>     observe: 'events',
>     params?: HttpParams,
>     reportProgress?: boolean,
>     responseType?: 'json',
>     withCredentials?: boolean,
>   }): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>
> ```
>
> Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns the full event stream.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the input. it's now working really well :-) @Injectable()
export class DocumentSearchService {
  
    constructor(private _http : HttpClient) { }
  
    getBucketList () : Observable<BucketList> {
  
      let serviceURL = "http://localhost:3000/listBuckets";
 
      return this._http.get<BucketList>(serviceURL);

    }
}